# Statistic: die manipulate in certain way, probability?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have a question regarding to an exercise:

A die is manipulated in such a way, that the probability of rolling a certain score is proportional to the corresponding numerical value (e.g. rolling the score “four” is twice as likely as rolling the score “two” and so on).

Determine the probability of the event:

1. A = odd number
2. B = prime number
3. C = even number
4. A, but not B

Can help me please somebody help me out? 
Greets!

Comment: Wrong stack? I think you might be after math.stackexchange.com

This stack is for the *software* **Mathematica**...